# How to trigger a event when a dropdown is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger a event to refresh all the options of dropdown, when we are opening it. And make sure that event won't get fired when we close the dropdown or select any option in it.

I am using following html code for dropdown.

```
<select id="SelectedNic" class="dropdown" name="SelectedNic" type="text">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="A">B</option>
    <option value=C">D</option>
 </select>
```

Could anyone suggest the right way of doing it? I am using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.on("focus", callback)` to do this. It will only get triggered when you dropdown will get active and not when you will close it or select any option.

```js
$("#SelectedNic").on("focus", function(){
  console.log("Opened");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectedNic" class="dropdown" name="SelectedNic" type="text">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="A">B</option>
    <option value=C">D</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using both change and keydown simultaneously.

```
 $('#SelectedNic').on('change keydown', function () {
     RegisterPanelChangeHandler();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a function call on `focus` of select box. `click` event will be fired even well closing it.

```
<select onFocus="myFunction()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="A">B</option>
    <option value=C">D</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using val() to change to the value and  trigger() to manually fire the event.
```

The change event handler must be declared before the trigger.

```js
$('#SelectedNic').change(function(){
  var data= $(this).val();
  alert(data);            
});

$('#SelectedNic')
    .val('A')
    .trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="SelectedNic" class="dropdown" name="SelectedNic" type="text">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="A">B</option>
    <option value="C">D</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla JS, I prefer 'focusin'  instead of 'focus' event, because the former bubbles.

With jQuery, you will use 'focus', jQuery fixes it for us.

```js
let sltEl = document.getElementById('select-el')
sltEl.addEventListener('focusin', evt => {
  console.log('opened')
})
```

```html
<select id="select-el" class="dropdown" name="selectEl">
    <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
    <option value="A">B</option>
    <option value="C">D</option>
 </select>
```